# Catchable fatal error Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: string, fatal-error

Catchable fatal error:

```
Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in 
wp-content/themes/techzine-theme/functions.php on line 163
```

Code starting at line 163:

```
} else {
$cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, " $separator ");
echo $before . the_title('','',false) . $after;
}
```